# django custom date_field widget by datepicker

Tags: django, datepicker, django-widget

So, I want to use a JS library called datepicker as a template for my date fields in forms.

My custom widget`s code just renders a template:

```
class MyDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        template = loader.get_template('date_widget.html')
        return template.render(Context({}))
```

and **date_widget.html** contains following

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp-input1" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
  <input class="span12" size="16" type="text" value="12-02-2012" readonly="">
  <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" onclick="$('#dp-input1').datepicker();"></i></span>
</div>
```

this html is kind of ok, I can see the nice popup datepicker menu in my page, but for some reason `request.POST` (this form posts, yes) doesn`t contain the picked date. Other fields are presented into the POST data.

Apparently my widget misses some important "backend" logic.

Comment: request won't pick up the value since input doesn't have `name` attribute..

Comment: seams correct, gonna check later, thnx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is pretty old, I think you must add the name attribute to the input tag:

```
class MyDateWidget(SelectDateWidget):

def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
    template = loader.get_template('date_widget.html')
    return template.render(Context({'name': name}))
```

And:

```
<div class="input-append date" id="dp-input1" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
    <input class="span12" size="16" type="text" name="{{ name }}" value="12-02-2012" readonly="">
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-calendar" onclick="$('#dp-input1').datepicker();"></i></span>
</div>
```